# How to filter array with arraylist using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to filter an array with a simple array list but I can't seem to figure out how, I tried using a custom filter but I can't make it work.
Edit: I've added more code. Text box Search works fine but when I add the myFilterby on the ng-repeat it no longer filters. I simply want to filter out an array list.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search .." ng-model="searchText">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </button>
    </span>
</div>
</div>

<td ng-repeat="a in product| filter:searchText | filter:myFilterBy">
    <img class="avatar" src="img/{{a.image}}" alt="">
    <div class="middleT">
        <p>{{a.brand}} {{a.model}} </p>
        <p>${{a.price}} </p>
    </div>
```

Angular:

```
var HandleModule = angular.module("HandleModule",['rzModule','ui.bootstrap','angular.filter']);
HandleModule.controller('HandleCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    // get data from the server in JSON format
   $scope.chk0 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
    $http.get('./loader.php').then(successCallback, errorCallback);
    function successCallback(response){
    //success code
    $scope.product = response.data;
    }
    function errorCallback(error){
    //error code
    $scope.product="error";
    }


$scope.myFilterBy = function(e) {
    return $scope.chk0.indexOf(e) !== -1;
}
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","product");
$query = "SELECT id, model, brand, price, description, image,  FROM fruits ORDER BY id";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$fruits= array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
$fruits[] = $row;
 }
echo json_encode($fruits);


?>
```

Used NG-repeat to print out the data separately. I used ng-repeat to display on html

```
  <p ng-repeat="a in products ">
  {{a}}
```

```
{"id":"1","model":"test1","brand":"orange","price":"4",
 "description":"orange sweet and sour","image":"orange.jpg"}

{"id":"2","model":"test2","brand":"banana","price":"3",
 "description":"yellow sweet","image":"banana.jpg"}

{"id":"3","model":"test3","brand":"apple","price":"5",
 "description":" red sweet crunchy","image":"apple.jpg"}
```

Comment: Please include the definition for the product array in your question.

Comment: can you add the `product` and `searchText` to your question?

Comment: The argument `e` of `myFilterBy` will be an object (like `a` in `ng-repeat`). You should pass one of its properties to `indexOf` instead of passing it itself: `return $scope.chk0.indexOf( e.somePropertyProbablyModel ) !== -1;`

Comment: @jbrown product array is from a mysql table. It loads perfectly without the myFilterBy function.

Comment: @Claies searchText is just a textbox to search from the list, it functions properly without adding the additional filter myFilterBy (when i do this it loads nothing.)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir did try this using e.brand did not work.

Comment: Are you sure there are objects in your `product` array whose `brand` value is either `"apple"`, `"orange"` or `"banana"`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes it works if i remove filter:myFilterby and type apple orange or banana in the search box.

Comment: well I marked the question as off topic due to your reluctance to provide a [mcve].  Multiple people asked you to add additional **code examples** of your data, and your responses essentially argue the point that they are needed.  It doesn't matter if they load without the filter, we can't see what the filter is supposed to do if we don't have a complete picture.

Comment: @Claies I apologize I've added more code. This is the first time  posting on here and I've spent over a day figuring out what is seemingly a simple problem.

Comment: the php code isn't really helpful, but I can see you are trying to improve the question.  what we are really looking for is a sample of what the actual data looks like, regardless of where it came from. maybe the JSON being returned from the server?  and it doesn't have to be real data, just something that represents what we are working with.

Comment: @Claies I've added the data, I used ng-repeat to display it on html

Answer (score 0):

From what I can decipher from your question and subsequent comments, you are simply trying to filter your product array by search text that is input by the user and a static array.

Your issue is that you are trying to compare an object to an array of strings.  To fix your problem you should compare an object property, in this case brand, against the array of strings.

You can see it working below.  For simplicity I have removed any code that wasn't essential to this issue.

```js
var HandleModule = angular.module("HandleModule", []);
HandleModule.controller('HandleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.chk0 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];

  $scope.product = [{
    "id": "1",
    "model": "test1",
    "brand": "orange",
    "price": "4",
    "description": "orange sweet and sour",
    "image": "orange.jpg"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "model": "test2",
    "brand": "banana",
    "price": "3",
    "description": "yellow sweet",
    "image": "banana.jpg"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "model": "test3",
    "brand": "apple",
    "price": "5",
    "description": "red sweet crunchy",
    "image": "apple.jpg"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "model": "test4",
    "brand": "pear",
    "price": "6",
    "description": "red sweet crunchy",
    "image": "pear.jpg"
  }];

  $scope.myFilterBy = function(e) {
    return $scope.chk0.indexOf(e.brand) >= 0;
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="HandleModule">

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="HandleCtrl">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search .." ng-model="searchText" />
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="a in product| filter:searchText | filter:myFilterBy">
          <div>
            <p>{{a.brand}} {{a.model}} </p>
            <p>${{a.price}} </p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works great and is exactly what i need but issue im having is this only works when I add the data array to the code itself. If i try to use the php imported one it doesn't load anything using | filter:myFilterBy . If I remove this filter everything loads fine. Having chk0 empty or holding the exact values from the data makes no different - nothing will display.